# Reaching all videos not manually

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im learning some JS and jQuery. I have page with 4 videos.
I want when ever i click a button, one vidoe opens and all the others will be hidden.
what I did untill now is:

```
<button class="lesson" id="fourthBut" >4</button>
<button class="lesson" id="thirdBut">3</button>
<button class="lesson"id="secondBut">2</button>
<button class="lesson" id="firstBut" >1</button>


<video src="WhatsApp Video 2021-08-28 at 10.24.46.mp4" controls="true" id="firstVid" class="VidStyle"></video>
```

```
$('#firstVid').hide()
$('#secondVid').hide()
$('#thirdVid').hide()
$('#fourthVid').hide()
$('#firstPar').hide()
$('#secondPar').hide()
$('#thirdPar').hide()
$('#fourthPar').hide()
$('#firstBut').on('click',function()
{   
    $('#firstVid').show(400)
    $('#secondVid').hide()
    $('#thirdVid').hide()
    $('#fourthVid').hide()
    $('#firstPar').show(800)
    $('#secondPar').hide()
    $('#thirdPar').hide()
    $('#fourthPar').hide()
});
```

(there are more 3 same sections)
I would like to do this through a loop, and not manually, becuase I will add new videos and probably alot.
I thought about saving all the video's id in an array and using it in order, but it didn't work, or I did it wrong
Please help, thanks!!

Comment: Can you please include the necessary code (HTML) for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use a class for all videos and when you click one of them show it and hide the other ones with that class.

Answer (score 1):

Give a class name for all the video elements.

```
<div class="videos_element" id="v1"></div>
<div class="videos_element" id="v2"></div>
<div class="videos_element" id="v3"></div>
```

Then add a data tag for the button to represent which video element is used for.

```
<button class="btnforvideo" data-id="v1">for video 1</button>
<button class="btnforvideo" data-id="v2">for video 2</button>
<button class="btnforvideo" data-id="v3">for video 3</button>
```

when the button is clicked hide all the video elements

```
$(document).on("click",".btnforvideo", function(){
   let data = $(this).data('id');
   $(".videos_element").hide();
   $(`#${data}`).show();
});
```

followed by showing the video element the button is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

With no inline javascript, Daniel Paul`s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69027381/4700922) is Ok. But you can also use named functions with arguments:

```js
function showVid(id){
    $(".VidStyle").hide();
    $("#vid"+id).show();
}
```

```css
#vid1{border:3px solid #ff0000}
#vid2{border:3px solid #00ff00}
#vid3{border:3px solid #ff00ff}
#vid4{border:3px solid #ffff00}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="lesson" onclick="showVid(1)">1</button>
<button class="lesson" onclick="showVid(2)">2</button>
<button class="lesson" onclick="showVid(3)">3</button>
<button class="lesson" onclick="showVid(4)">4</button>

<br><br>

<video src="1.mp4" controls="true" id="vid1" class="VidStyle"></video>
<video src="2.mp4" controls="true" id="vid2" class="VidStyle"></video>
<video src="3.mp4" controls="true" id="vid3" class="VidStyle"></video>
<video src="4.mp4" controls="true" id="vid4" class="VidStyle"></video>
```

Comment: I did a mistake, I thought its working but its not, I think there is problem with the  $("#vid"+id).show(); line, because it seems like it doesn't recognize the video from the id.

Comment: I have edited the answer so you can test the result in the code snippet. @BarSalem

Comment: working perfectly, I had other problem that prevented it from working. thanks alot!